# Can I use RxAndroid instead of Android Loader,HandlerThread,AsyncTask etc?

Tags: android

I am new to android, presently I am learning the concept of `asynchronous`. I notice that there are many concepts that can do `asynchronous` in Android. Some of them are:

1. JavaThread
2. HandlerThread
3. AsyncTask
4. Loader
5. RxAndroid
6. AsyncQueryHandler
7. Service
8. IntentService

My question is that, should I learn all of them or some of them. if some of them then which ones I should learn. please reply.

Comment: I haven't used all of them, but I would recommend starting with HandlerThread and then AsyncTask. Services are a bit different; they can exist independently of apps, and have different use-cases. That said, if you're new to programming, I'd recommend a scripting language like Python or NodeJS; Android can be weird and difficult

Comment: I would recommend you to learn all of them to have a good idea how it works well in Android. then start with service, intentService, AsyncTask, HandlerThread, Loader and then try RxAndroid+Rxjava (replacement of Asynctask and handler, looper etc). Learn in sequence with I have mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps stay away from IntentService, it's not concurrent-out of all your intent services only one instance can run at a time-and if it crashes, you won't be able to run any more intent services until the app process restarts eventually. /// This question is bound to attract opinionated answers and should be closed.

Comment: All of these are just implementations over a Java thread. I would learn about threads, rather than a specific framework implementation.  Concurrency is a discipline in its own right, and getting familiar with the base concepts is a good base to start from.  After that, personally, I'd learn RxJava (RxAndroid is just a subset of extras on top of RxJava).  Why? - 1) It's a common library 2) It's well used by the community 3) it's agnostic of a framework i.e. Android 4) once you learn RxJava you'll be able to use all the other language versions (5+ at present) as it's operator are the same.